# Tensorflow multi class classification loss

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've been recently trying to implement a multi-class classification LSTM architecture, based on this example: [biLSTM example](https://github.com/TobiasLee/Text-Classification/blob/master/models/attn_bi_lstm.py)

After I changed

```
self.label = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])
```

to

```
self.label = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None,self.n_class)
```

The model seems to train normally, yet I am having trouble with this step:

```
    self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=y_hat, labels=self.label))

    # prediction
    self.prediction = tf.argmax(tf.nn.softmax(y_hat), 1)
```

As, even though the model learns normally, the predictions does not seem to work for multiple variables. I was wondering how should one code the self.prediction object, so that it emits a vector of predictions for individual instances?

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you want to obtain the probability output instead of the label, how about just deleting `tf.argmax` part.  `self.prediction = tf.nn.softmax(y_hat)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering how should one code the self.prediction object, so
>   that it emits a vector of predictions for individual instances?

In general `tf.nn.softmax` returns a vector of probabilities. You just can't see them because your are using `tf.argmax`, which returns the index of the largest value. Therefore you will just get one number. Just remove tf.argmax and you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you, the probability matrix is exactly what I was after.

Comment: You're welcome. I would also appreciate an upvote :) Thanks!